# Macports force-activate all ports

Tags: macos, command-line, macports, open-source

When trying to install SciTE

```
sudo port install scite
```

port stops at

> Error: org.macports.activate for port gettext returned: Image error: **/opt/local/bin/autopoint** already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port gettext. Use 'port -f activate **gettext**' to force the activation.

but if I run `sudo port -f activate gettext` and re-try installing `scite`, I end up with the same error message, this time with **/opt/local/lib/libffi.6.dylib** and **libffi** and so on and so on...

How can I tell Macports to force activate all ports that stand in it's way from completing installing SciTE, without having to manually re-run the installation of the package I actually want and without having to copy-paste each activation command?

Comment: The obvious question is what happens if you back up your mac and then delete the problem file `/opt/local/bin/autopoint ` ?

Comment: Jove you upgraded OSX since installing Macports or restore /opt from a backup?

Comment: @bmike it's a different file each time, I made that clearer now.

Comment: @Mark I can't remember how all that /opt/ content got there. I had brew installed previously. More likely though: perhaps by installing one or multiple packages exported from Macports that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Oh dear - you might need to declare /opt bankruptcy and wipe/uninstall. I'm more versed in homebrew so I can't advise you on specifics here.. Hopefully a ports user can point out how to uninstall or repair a broken setup like you're reporting.

Comment: I would do as bike suggests and delete macports and start again https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html and remove all homebrew

Comment: I did `port -fp uninstall installed` but I guess that keeps /opt/local intact. I might have just to do the manual rm command.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install the desired port by automating the activation process. The app fails to run due to some library version issues and I seem to be unable to fix those but that's a story for another answer or another question.

1. Create a script that continuously tries to install the port and automatically forcefully activates the discovered port that is blocking it. Copy paste the following into a file and call it `port-instact.sh`

   ```
   if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
     then echo "Please run as root"
     exit
   fi
   target="$1"
   while [ 1 ]
   do
       echo trying to install "$target"
       if [[ $(port installed "$target" | grep "$target") ]]; then echo "$target" present; break; fi
       line=`port install "$target" 2>&1 > /dev/tty | grep "port -f activate"`
       package=$(echo $line | sed -e "s/^.*port -f activate //" -e "s/. .*//")
       if [ "$package" = "$oldpackage" ]; then echo double \""$package"\"; break; fi
       oldpackage="$package"
       echo activating "$package"
       port -f activate "$package"
   done
   ```
2. Make the file executable via `chmod +x port-instact.sh`
3. Run it as root `sudo ./port-instact.sh scite` and wait

Comment: Wow, surprised this isn't a regular option in MacPorts. Thanks!

Comment: would be even better if all the "Continue? [Y/n]: Y" can be piped to `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything Macports and reinstalling it allows you to normally install ports.

Use the elaborate rm command from [Macports guide (uninstalling)](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html):

```
sudo rm -rf \
        /opt/local \
        /Applications/DarwinPorts \
        /Applications/MacPorts \
        /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
        /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
        /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
        /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
        /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
        /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
        ~/.macports
```

Thanks to [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mark) for the suggestion.